# Bootstrap Mobile Navi not working only in 1 page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Page I'm working on](http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/projects.html)

On every other page, the mobile nav works fine. I just realized it does not work on the given page.

I'm using [jquery-easytabs](https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/). I am not sure if this plugin is causing the issue. Here's the code that I have:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header-sec">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"                      data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="logo2"><img src="image/Element-Design-logo.png"></div>
</div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="company.html">Our Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is you are loading jQuery twice. Try removing one instance of it from the head.

You have `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` Go with one, this could be a cause of conflict.

Comment: Don't know if you resolved it, but it seems to be working now. Also you have some path resolution errors for jquery.bxslider.css. If you're using Bootstrap, is there a reason you need to use bxslider as opposed to Bootstraps [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) or [collapse/accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to achieve what you need?

Comment: Yes i have resolved it. Just need to add div class row...duh.Took me a few days to realise it